# FFmpeg build configuration for just AAC, MP3, WAV

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, build

I need to use ffmpeg for just converting audio files between `AAC, MP3, WAV` only.

So I want to compile ffmpeg for my requirement.

But I don't know best `./configure bla bla bla...` commandline for my requirement.

Please help me. What is the best `./configure` command line for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [read the compilation guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) (this one is for Ubuntu and derivates, but there are others too). You only need `libmp3lame` installed, so you could simply run `apt-get install libmp3lame-dev`. Then, run:

```
./configure --enable-libmp3lame
```

As for your other requirements:

- For AAC encoding, use `-c:a aac -strict experimental` and set an appropriate bitrate. There is no VBR. If you want a better quality AAC encoder with VBR capabilities, compile ffmpeg with `libfdk_aac`.
- WAV output does not require any dependencies. Simply choose the audio codec you want and write to a .wav file, e.g. `-c:a pcm_s16le`. Remember that WAV is a file format, not an audio codec (WAV files can contain many different codecs).